# Bare pin arduino breadboard connection

Tags: arduino

I am on the software side of things and have, only recently, been trying to get into hardware. I have bought an arduino - ATMEGA 328 and got some examples on `pin 13` working.

Now I wish to connecting the arduino to the breadboard for more complicated stuff. My arduino is bare-pin and therefore I bought some 2-Way M-M headers (in picture 1) as 1-Way were not available and have plugged them into the breadboard and connected the same to the arduino as in picture - 2 using an F-F jumper wire.

I have to use the above set-up as M-F jumper cables are not available in the locality.

[image]
[image]

**Question**: Is the above set up safe (won't blow things of)? Also is a difference in FF jumper cables - I have 5-each of black and red colors in a pack of ten do they have different roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it looks quite safe (providing you don't connect up anything badly on the breadboard of course)
The jumper cables are physically the same, just the colours are usually used to denote different rails/signals to make it easier to remember what is what (or on a wiring diagram the colour/signal relationships would be noted to enable someone to find the required signal easily)
Often you might use e.g. red for +V and black for -V, but you can use them as you wish.

Comment: Tested it works beautifully!